# Unreal 5 and Maya 2020 not matching scale despite both defaulting to centimeters

Tags: models, fbx, maya, unreal-5

Effectively 100 units in Maya set in centimeters = 1 unit in Unreal Engine set to centimeters

I've been in a school project last year and am about to embark on another on UE5, and I'd like to find out if anyone has truly solved this (or have resigned to internalising the scale disparity and working 100x in maya)

- Maya Version: 2020.4
- Unreal Engine Version(s): 4.27, 5.0.3

  - both maya and UE default to centimeters and both are reviewed to be at such, as at time of writing.
- FBX versions tested: 2018, 2020

Method of testing:

- create unit cube in UE
- export FBX
- import to maya
- create pCube of length 1
- compare cubes and realise the UE cube is 100x bigger than the maya pCube
- reverse comparison (export unit pCube from maya to UE via FBX, receive tiny cube)

Long-running problem with bandaid visual "workarounds" been suggested, like adjusting the grid in maya to mimic the grid in UE.

https://knowledge.autodesk.com/support/maya-lt/learn-explore/caas/CloudHelp/cloudhelp/2018/ENU/MayaLT-DataExchange/files/GUID-DAB74E5F-58D2-49E7-B919-BED413F44FDE-htm.html

https://www.reddit.com/r/Maya/comments/a0hvrw/how_to_match_the_scale_and_grid_of_maya_to_unreal/

https://www.worldofleveldesign.com/categories/ue4/ue4-set-up-maya-grid-to-match-unreal-engine4.php

Sorry if I've gotten to the wrong section of the Stack site, I'm not sure which is causing this disparity here. Safe alternative suggestions would be appreciated (like changing units in the UE project without messing up physics), although we're really early on right now and can quickly do edits before the project starts getting big.